# Can not publishing static site on github

Tags: html, css, git, github, publish

I am trying to publish a static webpage but it shows this error below.

> 404 File not found
>
> The site configured at this address does not contain the requested
> file.
>
> If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the
> URL. For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an
> index.html file.

I have done everything right
one more error send on my email :

> The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following
> error:
>
> ```
> No `/docs` folder was found to build GitHub Pages. Check the source setting for this repository.
> ```

Comment: Use [edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65988687/edit) to improve your post... _"I have done everything right"_ Not clear what you did. How can those who use Github recreate your same problem? What address did you try to visit for error to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's written in the email (check the source settings for the repository) ;)

repository page -> Settings -> GitHub Pages -> Source -> select `root` OR `docs`

[image]

most of the projects have static html located in `/docs`

- change the default `/docs` -> `/`
- or move content into folder `/docs`

Comment: Thanks for responding but even i select docs then also I get an error msg :

Comment: Your site is having problems building: No /docs folder was found to build GitHub Pages. Check the source setting for this repository. For more information, see https://docs.github.com/github/working-with-github-pages/troubleshooting-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites#missing-docs-folder.

Answer (score 0):

Github pages needs an index.html at the root of the repo,may be can solve this problem